# Using bibleref with babel

Tags: babel

I'm trying to use the `bibleref` package together with `[french]{babel}`, and failing. The bibleref documentation warns that it doesn't play nice, and that you might have to make colons non-active with babel.

How do I do that?

I've tried using `\shorthandoff{:}` but it doesn't seem to help. Forgetting about `babel` would make my life much harder to have proper French rules.

To be more specific, here is the error I'm getting when calling `pdflatex` on my file:

```
Runaway argument?
5:21) 
! Paragraph ended before \@bibleverse was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.73 

?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use `\shorthandoff{:}` after `\begin{document}` or enclose it within `\AtBeginDocument` in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\AtBeginDocument{\shorthandoff{:}}

\usepackage{bibleref}

\begin{document}

\bibleverse{Exod}(20:17)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What are the consequences on `babel` of doing this?

Comment: @Raphink: My guess is that babel does not automatically add a space before colons (which seems to be the norm in French typography).

Comment: Would it be a good idea to write a new command like `\newcommand{\bbibleverse}[2]{\shorthandoff{:}\bibleverse{#1}#2\shorthandon{:}}` ?

Comment: @Raphink: Maybe -- I don't know what `\bibleref` does and what adverse effects might emerge. Another possibility is to define a new babel shorthand that copies the default defintion of `:` and to use the new shorthand in the text.